# wso2 carbon - student management example for 4.0

Tags: wso2

I've followed the excellent tutorial [here](http://wso2.org/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components) for creating my own carbon components based on carbon 3.0.

What are the changes that are needed to the instructions to make the example run on carbon 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only edit you have to make is at feature level, Where we explicitly say, in order this feature to work you need Carbon 4.x.x features in your runtime.

In the features pom.xml you have to do something like

```
<importFeatures>
       <importFeatureDef>org.wso2.carbon.core:4.0.0</importFeatureDef>
```

Other than that rest should work fine without a problem. Sometime back i ported the sample to work with Carbon 4.0.0. I'm attaching the new zip. I did not verify before attaching. It should work.

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bz93FnJ8mzOrTGRweElSNWlQeU0

hth